# chart.add_data(values) TypeError

Tags: python, openpyxl

I started working on an excel worksheet, and I encounter an error that I don't know how to fix.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference



wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for row in range (2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell (row, 3)
    correct_price = cell.value * 0.9
    correct_price_cell = sheet.cell (row, 4)
    correct_price_cell.value = correct_price

values = Reference (sheet, min_row=2, max_row=sheet.max_row, min_col=4, max_col=4)

chart = BarChart
chart.add_data(values)
sheet.add_chart (chart, 'e2')


wb.save('transcations2.xlsx')
```

The error that I get is :

```
chart.add_data(values)
TypeError: add_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

I don't know which argument I need to add for this.

Comment: You haven't created a new chart object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, sorry for the dumb question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. If you're going to answer your own question (which is encouraged!) please make sure to include the actual solution so other people can be helped as well.